# HOW TO FIX: You do not have permission to view this directory or page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have a new legacy code in .NET MVC app.

The first time a run it, prompt the windows authentication alert to log me in. I already disabled it in the web.config.

Then a see authentication code obviously, but i already comment it to jump.

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //if (!Request.IsAuthenticated) return;

        //var userPrincipal = new CompanyPrincipal((WindowsIdentity) HttpContext.Current.User.Identity);
        //var userPrincipal = new CompanyPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent());

        //if (userPrincipal.IsAuthenticated)
        //{
            //HttpContext.Current.User = userPrincipal;
        WindowsPrincipal fakeUser = new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent());
        HttpContext.Current.User = fakeUser;
        //}
        //else
        //{
        //    Response.StatusCode = 401;
        //    Response.StatusDescription = "Unauthorized";
        //    Response.SuppressContent = true;
        //    HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        //}
    }
```

After this something my app displays the error message **HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized**

[HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized - image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aF5Fq.png)

And this is part of my web config

```
<system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
        <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
        <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
        <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
      </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

and this part

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <globalization culture="es-MX" uiCulture="es-MX" />
    <!--<authentication mode="Windows" />-->    
    <authentication mode="None"/>    
    <authorization>
         <allow users="*" />
         <!--<deny users="*" />-->
      </authorization>
  </system.web>
```

What am i missing?? I already give permissons to application folders but i think there is something more there.

Any suggestion?? I have some bindings and end points in the web.config.

Regards!!

Comment: Is this IIS site configured as an ASP.NET app? If not, this might just be an IIS error and not ASP.NET.

Comment: I am running the app in IIS Express, without deploy. but i do not have enough knowledge about IIS configuration. did i answer your question??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a windows principal maybe you should change the authentication mode to "Windows".

Comment: but if i want to jump the authentication how, what can i do??

Answer (score 1):

In my case There is a filter enabled in `App_Start => FilterConfig.cs =>  "filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());"`
I just removed above line and now my application is working fine.
Thanks!